# How to get the System font in an iOS app?

Tags: ios, fonts, xamarin.ios, xamarin, system-font

I am using Xamarin Studio to develop an iOS iPad app. I need to assign the System font name to a variable in the code behind on one of the pages.

How do I get whatever the System font is programmatically?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

*NOTE: Before somebody thinks he has to change this answer: This is answering a question about Xamarin.iOS and not ObjectiveC. The API really uses uppercase properties and method names.*

Create a system UIFont and read its properties:

```
var font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(10);
string familyName = font.FamilyName;
string fontName = font.Name;
```

See also Apple's reference for [UIFont](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIFont_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006891-CH4-SW15).

Answer (score 5):

Starting with iOS7, you have a richer way of getting the font, using the new UIFont properties.

For details see:

http://tirania.org/monomac/archive/2013/Sep-25.html